# Why does the for loop assign a value equal to 6 for the fourth iteration?

Tags: r

This simple for loop takes the maximum value in each row, subtracts the minimum value, and assigns the result to column "e" in the corresponding row. All resulting values in column "e" are correct except the last, which should equal 3. However, the for loop returns 6 as the answer.

```
#data frame
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,0,3,9),
            b=c(2,3,2,8),
            c=c(3,6,1,7),
            d=c(4,9,4,6))

#Simple for loop to generate new, calculated column "e"
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$e[i] <- max(df[i,])-min(df[i,])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a loop where you don't need to add any intermediary objects (other than i):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) df[i, "e"] <- max(df[i,], na.rm=T) - min(df[i,], na.rm=T)

df

  a b c d e
1 1 2 3 4 3
2 0 3 6 9 9
3 3 2 1 4 3
4 9 8 7 6 3
```

- note: `na.rm` is needed as the value of `df[2:nrow(df),"e"]` was assigned as `NA` when `i <-1`

Comment: Why do     df[i,"e"]    and     df$e[i]    produce different outcomes in your example?

Comment: `df$e[1] <- max(df[1,])- min(df[1,])` will force `df[2:4, "e"]` to have a value of df$e[1]. This will have no effect on rows 2 and 3, since the value `3` is not the min or max value. For row 4 though, this value of '3' will be taken as the min value, so the resultant calculation will give you `9-3`.

Comment: Thank you. This explanation really helps me to understand the root of the problem and how the loop is operating.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `apply`

```
df$e <- apply(df, 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
df$e
#[1] 3 9 3 3
```

---

Another option is `rowRanges` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df$e <- c(diff(t(rowRanges(as.matrix(df)))))
df$e
#[1] 3 9 3 3
```

---

In the `for` loop, we can create a temporary object to assign the values and then update the 'e' column

```
tmp <- numeric(nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 tmp <- (max(df[i,]) - min(df[i,]))

}

df$e <- tmp
df$e
#[1] 3 9 3 3
```

Comment: Why is a 'tmp' object necessary, and why can't the 'df' object be added to directly within the for loop?

Comment: @DaleKube The execution and assignment doesn't happen at the same time in the loop